starting in iot
I have a background in embedded systems and am now interested in expanding my knowledge to include Internet of Things (IoT) technologies. I’m looking for suggestions on where to start and how to effectively transition into this field.
Could you recommend any resources, courses, or communities that would be helpful for someone with my background? Any guidance on getting started with IoT concepts, tools, and best practices would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

questions that seek an opinion are off topic here, because all answers are equally correct ... how would you choose a "correct" answer anyway?

I think IOT is broad gray topic that lacks clear boarders. If someone put that on their resume I would not ask what they did but rather why they put it on their resume. That said, if you have done embedded programming where you communicated to another embedded device or a computer, you've already done most of what I believe IOT is.
